# How to find bytes in binary file C

Tags: c, file, binary, antivirus, strstr

How to find bytes in binary file.
I read the binary file to a string and try to do "strstr()"
It doesn't work. if I print the string in loop as %c the string is dont look the same but if I print as %x or %02hhX it looks the same.
I open two binary file and try to see if one file is hiding in the other file. to kind of anti virus code.

my code:

```
    FILE* file = fopen(filePath, "rb");
    FILE* signature = fopen(signaturePath, "rb"); 

    fread(fileStr, fileSize, 1, file);

    fread(signatureStr, signatureSize, 1, signature);

    int in = strstr(fileStr, signatureStr);

    if (in)
    {
        printf("bytes found.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("sorry...\n");
    }
```

Comment: Downvoted because incomplete code.

Answer (score 2):

> I read the binary file to a string

You don't though. You just read it into an array of characters. How could you? The end of a string is marked by a zero byte, and a binary file may contain zero bytes inside it. So unless you perform some kind of conversion that escapes any zero bytes, you *don't* have a string.

The `str*` functions are only useful on strings. They aren't useful for arbitrary binary data. Instead, use the `mem*` functions. If you don't have `memmem`, it can easily be implemented. There's [one written by an engineer at Apple](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-825.26/string/FreeBSD/memmem.c.auto.html) that's open source.